# Python streaming data to S3 but getting 104 error is this the best way

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am currently trying to stream an API response to S3 as a JSON file. I can not write to the local drive. But I keep getting "104 Connection reset by peer" errors. I'm wondering if my code is the best way to do this and if it could be contributing to the problem?

This is my current method

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')
s3object = s3.Object(s3_bucket, output_file)
s3object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(obj).encode('UTF-8'))))
```

Comment: What region is the bucket you are trying to connect to located?

Comment: its located: eu-west-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an accepted [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2207) in boto. There is nothing wrong with your approach. Maybe try creating a bucket in another region. Or if it is possible capture data locally then upload it to s3.